# Where in the standard (C++11) is it said that the remainder operator works for integral type only?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I would like a pointer in the standard (n3242/3291/3290) about where it is defined that the remainder operator doesn't apply to floating point type.

The remainder operator `%` is defined in **5.6.2**

> The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary % operator yields
>       the remainder from the division of the first expression by the second. If the
>       second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined. For integral operands
>       the / operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded
>       if the quotient a/b is representable in the type of the result, (a/b)*b + a%b is
>       equal to a.

I can't find where it is forbidden to use a floating point type. And the fact the standard explicitly treats `integral operands` as a special case could be interpreted as: the operator exists for other non-integral types.

I know that MSVC and GCC doesn't accept it, and I looked at lots of answers about this issue, but I can't get a valid pointer in the C++ 11 standard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++11, 5.6/2:

> The operands of `*` and `/` shall have arithmetic or unscoped enumeration type; **the operands of `%` shall have
>   integral or unscoped enumeration type**. The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands
>   and determine the type of the result.

(Emphasis mine)